# saving collection to database using simple_form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, simple-form

I am using simple form to make checkboxes as below:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def all_colors
      t = [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
      ]
      return t
end
```

`<%= f.input :colors, :label=>false, :collection => all_colors, :as => :check_boxes%>`

When the user selects some checkboxes and submits the form, the data saved in databases also has non selected items empty location.

For example If user checkmarked `B` and `D` then data saved in DB will look like:

```
--- 
- ""
- B
- ""
- D
```

I want the data to be saved as `CSV`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance it seems to me you might be passing extra commas in your input so when your user checkmarked B and D what got passed back in the request was- `,B,D,`. 
When you parse the input to save the extra commas were translated into empty values.
Check the request variables that were posted back by the form submit and strip away the extra commas.